# Map and Cardview Activities

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design

Is there a way I can have a **RecyclerView/Cardview** overlaying a maps activity like the example picture I have linked here?

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99PN2.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the example of what you are trying to achieve:**

Libraries required: 
`compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'`

`compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'`

Sample XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|start">

         <!-- YOUR MAP FRAGMENT HERE -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/parallax_image_height"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/putin" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/anchor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/parallax_image_height"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/parallax_image_height" />

        <!-- YOUR RECYCLER VIEW REPLACES SCROLLVIEW AND CARDS -->

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/anchor">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/large_text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/large_text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/large_text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/large_text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/large_text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/large_text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_title"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                        android:paddingStart="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/large_text"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.github.ksoichiro.android.observablescrollview.ObservableScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ObservableScrollViewCallbacks {

private View mImageView;
private ObservableScrollView mScrollView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
    mScrollView = (ObservableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
    mScrollView.setScrollViewCallbacks(this);

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    onScrollChanged(mScrollView.getCurrentScrollY(), false, false);
}

@Override
public void onScrollChanged(int scrollY, boolean firstScroll, boolean dragging) {
    ViewHelper.setTranslationY(mImageView, scrollY / 2);
}

@Override
public void onDownMotionEvent() {

}

@Override
public void onUpOrCancelMotionEvent(ScrollState scrollState) {

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Cool Mohit Verma.  I will inserting this into the Navigation drawer Content_Home xml!!