# How to prevent Scrollview from intercepting touch?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview, android-framelayout

I have a Frame Layout. Inside the Frame layout in the lower frame i have a map fragment and in the upper frame i have Scrollview. I want the content of scrollview overlap the Map on scrolling but i also want the map to be accessible when the scrollview content hasn't overlapped the map.

Here is my layout file

```
<FrameLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"

            >

            <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                tools:context=".MapLocationActivity"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_place_black_24dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:clickable="false"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            >

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etAdd"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Address"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Address"
                    />


                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Address"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Address"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Address"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Address"
                    />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Address"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Address"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

I want to achieve something like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should use Coordinator layout with Collapsing Toolbar layout

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati i don't want  the Map to get compressed i want it to get overlapped.

Comment: I doubt if overlapping would look good. You can use RelativeLayout, first child will be your Map fragment following it will be the scrollview. They both will overlap.

Comment: @MuraliPrajapati the major problem is that on overlapping the scrollview is intercepting the touch event hence i cannot access the map fragment. The scrollview is overlapping the map so that's not the problem.

Comment: @rustedbrain i tried your suggestion but still the problem is that the scrolllview is making the map unclickable

Comment: Scrollview is behaving normally. To make `Scrollview` not handle touch events you have to write your own touch interceptor using `scrollView.onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)`. Why would you even want to overlap both the components in the first place? Wouldn't that look bad UI wise as well as in your code?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/45183288/6448973](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45183288/6448973)